# Founding maxima or minima to a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

$g(x)=e^{x-1}+x^{2}-3+2x$

How can I find when this function has maxima and minima?

I found the derivative but I can't understand how find the solution when $g'(x)=0$. It's high school material.

Comment: What did you get when you took the derivative?

Comment: Are you asking if this function has a maximum or a minimum or are you trying to find the value of a maximum or a minimum?
If you are trying to find the value, you will have to solve an equation either by using approximations or using the LambertW function.

Comment: I am trying to find the value. The real question is when the function "goes up" or "goes down". It's school question.

Comment: @NeilRauch finding when the function "goes up" or "goes down" is an entirely different matter from finding minima and maxima

Comment: I guess so. any way it is also intresting question. (the real value, that is why I asked it). 
But in matter of fact the thing that is most important for me now is the domain when the function "goes up\down". (English is not my native language. sorry for using the wrong terms)

Answer (score 0):

$$g'(x) = e^{x-1} + 2x + 2$$
$$g''(x) = e^{x-1} + 2$$

The first derivative tells you the amount of increase of the curve $g$. For minima and maxima you are therefore looking for a point that is non-increasing and non-decreasing. It "looks" flat. A tangent (think of it as a flat hat) can be placed on it.

What you have to do is find the solution to the equation:

$$g'(x) = e^{x-1} + 2x + 2 = 0$$

This will give you a list of some points. What you have to do then is check if a found point is a minimum or maximum, or just a saddle-point (a point where you can place a flat hat, but that increases on one side and decreases on the other side).
For this you can use the second derivative: If $g''$ at given point is positive, then the point is a minimum, if it is negative, then the point is a maximum. If it is zero then it is a saddle point.

Comment: The thing is, I am not sure how to solve this equation. $g(x)').$

Comment: Also if you don't mind, this equation $e^x-2e\times x^0.5$ I think it is understood which kind of equations I don't know how to solve. thanks in advanced.

Comment: @NeilRauch where did you encounter this exercise/problem? it is not trivial to solve it. The numerical solution is approximately -1.0635

Comment: Please see the comment in the original post.